# Two querysets in one view in Django

Tags: python, django

so I'm trying to make two lists in one view but with different filters. They also change whether the campaign is paused or is running. This is what I came up with but it throws this error: **TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset_paused'**

This is my views.py

```
def home_view(request):
    #campaigns in progress
    queryset = Campaign.objects.filter(is_active=True, completion_percent__lt=100)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_type = request.POST.get('id')
        if form_type == 'campaign_status':
            formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                request.POST, request.FILES,
                queryset=queryset,
            )
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset=queryset)

    campaigns_and_forms = list(zip(queryset, formset))

    #paused campaigns
    queryset_paused = Campaign.objects.filter(is_active=False, completion_percent__lt=100)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form_type = request.POST.get('id_paused')
        if form_type == 'campaign_status_paused':
            formset_paused = CampaignStatusFormSet(
                request.POST, request.FILES,
                queryset_paused=queryset_paused,
            )
            formset_paused.save()
    else:
        formset_paused = CampaignStatusFormSet(queryset_paused=queryset_paused)

    campaigns_and_forms_paused = list(zip(queryset_paused, formset_paused))

    context = {
        'formset': formset,
        'campaigns_and_forms': campaigns_and_forms,
        'formset_paused': formset_paused,
        'campaigns_and_forms_paused': campaigns_and_forms_paused,
    }

    return render(request, 'campaigns_in_progress.html', context)
```

Here is my template for the two lists

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bright table-bordered align-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
            <th scope="col">Temat</th>
            <th scope="col">Nadawca</th>
            <th scope="col">Procent Realizacji</th>
            <th scope="col">Start Kampani</th>
            <th scope="col">Stan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form method="post" id="campaign_status"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' value='campaign_status' name='id'>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for campaign, form in campaigns_and_forms %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ campaign.campaign_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.topic }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.sender }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{campaign.completion_percent}}%;" aria-valuenow="{{campaign.completion_percent}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{campaign.completion_percent}}%</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.as_p }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h4>Kampanie wstrzymane</h4>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bright table-bordered align-middle">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nazwa</th>
            <th scope="col">Temat</th>
            <th scope="col">Nadawca</th>
            <th scope="col">Procent Realizacji</th>
            <th scope="col">Start Kampani</th>
            <th scope="col">Stan</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <form method="post" id="campaign_status_paused"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' value='campaign_status_paused' name='id_paused'>
    {{ formset_paused.management_form }}
    {% for campaign, form in campaigns_and_forms_paused %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ campaign.campaign_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.topic }}</td>
            <td>{{ campaign.sender }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{campaign.completion_percent}}%;" aria-valuenow="{{campaign.completion_percent}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{campaign.completion_percent}}%</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{ campaign.start_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.as_p }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I think you need to change `queryset_paused=queryset_paused,` to `queryset=queryset_paused,`?

Comment: @BrianDestura that worked but now when ever I change start/stop it shows this error: UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'formset_paused' referenced before assignment

Comment: This is because `formset_paused` will be undeclared if `request.method == "POST"` but `form_type` is not `campaign_status_paused`

Comment: @BrianDestura But 'form_type' will always be 'campaign_status_paused' there is no other option. What should I write in the 'else' statement that won't do anything?